# Sencha: Store proxy chain

Tags: sencha-touch

I would like to load data from a localStorage proxy, but if it is not found there, then load it from an Ajax proxy, and cache it in localStorage. Is there a way to setup a proxy chain in Sencha, or do I have to implement this on my own?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a localstorage proxy to your model and load the store first. This will load the data from localstore. If you get store.getCount() = 0, then there is no data in the localstorage and you can setup ajax proxy and load data.

There is no inbuilt method for this - so, you have to make it work yourself above way.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing. I have a class that extends Store, and adds ability to failover to a secondary store.

Comment: @alekop Can you post some code here ? I would appreciate to see your solution.